# Wordpress Theme Options Page - Radio Buttons not updating correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, radio-button, themes

I am currently working on the Theme Options Page of my Wordpress Theme.

As a base I'm using the "[SAMPLE WORDPRESS THEME OPTIONS PAGE](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/)" by Ian Steward:

### The Situation:

I've implemented two sets of radio-buttons like so:
[image]

### The Problem:

They work as planned, the chosen options are applied.

Only problem: after saving the chosen radio buttons aren't selected anymore.

For the image above: If I would change both radio buttons and click save only the very first radio button is selected, after the page has loaded again.

### The Code:

From the theme-options.php:

```
// Normal/Fixed Navigation Options
$fixed_navigation_options = array(
    'Normal' => array(
        'value' => ' ',
        'label' => __( 'Normal', 'arrowcatch' )
    ),
    'Fixed' => array(
        'value' => 'is-fixed',
        'label' => __( 'Fixed', 'arrowcatch' )
    )
);


// Full-width/Contained Navigation Options
$contained_navigation_options = array(
    'Full-width' => array(
        'value' => ' ',
        'label' => __( 'Full-width', 'arrowcatch' )
    ),
    'Contained' => array(
        'value' => 'is-contained',
        'label' => __( 'Contained', 'arrowcatch' )
    )
);
```

---

```
function arrowcatch_theme_options_page() {
global $select_options, $fixed_navigation_options, $contained_navigation_options;
if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) )
    $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] = false; ?>

<div class="wrap"> 

<?php if ( false !== $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) : ?> 
<div class="updated fade">
    <p><strong>Options saved!</strong></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

---

```
<!-- Normal/Fixed Navigation -->
    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Navigation Normal/Fixed', 'arrowcatch' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <fieldset><legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e( 'Navigation Normal/Fixed', 'arrowcatch' ); ?></span></legend>
            <?php
                if ( ! isset( $checked ) )
                    $checked = '';
                foreach ( $fixed_navigation_options as $option ) {
                    $fixed_navigation_setting = $options['fixed_navigation'];
                    if ( '' != $fixed_navigation_setting ) {
                        if ( $options['fixed_navigation'] == $option['value'] ) {
                            $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
                        } else {
                            $checked = '';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <label class="description"><input type="radio" name="arrowcatch_theme_options[fixed_navigation]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $option['value'] ); ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> /> <?php echo $option['label']; ?></label><br />
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>


<!-- Full-width/Contained Navigation -->
    <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Navigation Full-width/Contained', 'arrowcatch' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <fieldset><legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e( 'Navigation Full-width/Contained', 'arrowcatch' ); ?></span></legend>
            <?php
                if ( ! isset( $checked ) )
                    $checked = '';
                foreach ( $contained_navigation_options as $option ) {
                    $contained_navigation_setting = $options['contained_navigation'];
                    if ( '' != $contained_navigation_setting ) {
                        if ( $options['fixed_navigation'] == $option['value'] ) {
                            $checked = "checked=\"checked\"";
                        } else {
                            $checked = '';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <label class="description"><input type="radio" name="arrowcatch_theme_options[contained_navigation]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $option['value'] ); ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?> /> <?php echo $option['label']; ?></label><br />
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

---

Hope that's all the code thats needed.

Not sure what's going on there.

I'm very thankfull for any push in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: echo anywere $options['fixed_navigation'] and compare it with $option['value'], patebin/tell us the results; also in the "Full-width/Contained Navigation" part where you have if ( '' != $contained_navigation_setting ) {
                        if ( $options['fixed_navigation'] == $option['value'] ). shouldn't that be if ($options['contained_navigation'] == $option['value'])?

Comment: Hi alex alex, 
wow, the "($options['contained_navigation'] == $option['value'])" what exactely where things went wrong. Everything's working perfect now. Thanks so much, I just didn't see that mistake.